# How to update (merge) when similar item exists in the table

Tags: sql, vertica

(Edit: In case anyone would like to try, this is the SQL Fiddle URL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39c72c/1)

Suppose I have table `A` which looks like below:

```
col_1    col_2    cnt_1    mapped_val
  A1       B1        10     mapped_A1
  A2       B2         5     mapped_A2
  A3       B3         0     mapped_A3
....
```

I also have table `B` which looks like below:

```
col_1    col_2    cnt_1    mapped_val
  A1       B1        20     update_to_this
  A2       B2         5     do_not_update_to_this
  D1       D2         5     mapped_D1
  E3       E3         0     mapped_E3
....
```

For each of the row in table `B`, I'd like to look it up in table `A` using `col_1` and `col_2`, AND if `cnt_1` of table `A` is smaller than that of table `B`, then I'd like to update `cnt_1` and `mapped_val` entries in table `A` with that of table `B`. For the ones from table `B` that does not match, I'd like to append them to table `A`. The result by applying such an operation to table `A` would be:

```
col_1    col_2    cnt_1    mapped_val
  A1       B1        20     update_to_this
  A2       B2         5     mapped_A2
  A3       B3         0     mapped_A3
  D1       D2         5     mapped_D1
  E3       E3         0     mapped_E3
....
```

I think `MERGE INTO` (please see my best try below) comes close to accomplishing this, but I'm not sure how to implement comparison logic as part of `MERGE INTO` query.

```
MERGE INTO 
    A AS a
USING
    B AS b
ON 
    a.col_1 = b.col_1
    AND
    a.col_2 = b.col_2
WHEN MATCHED -- AND a.cnt_1 < b.cnt_1?
    THEN UPDATE 
        SET 
            a.cnt_1 = b.cnt_1,
            a.mapped_val = b.mapped_val
WHEN NOT MATCHED -- AND a.cnt_1 < b.cnt_1?
    THEN INSERT
        (col_1, col_2, cnt_1, mapped_val)
    VALUES
        (b.col_1, b.col_2, b.cnt_1, b.mapped_val);
```

Thank you in advance for your answers/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about Vertica syntax, but I believe this should simply work:

```
MERGE INTO 
    A AS a
USING
    B AS b
ON 
    a.col_1 = b.col_1
    AND
    a.col_2 = b.col_2
    AND 
    a.cnt_1 < b.cnt_1
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE 
        SET 
            a.cnt_1 = b.cnt_1,
            a.mapped_val = b.mapped_val
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT
        (col_1, col_2, cnt_1, mapped_val)
    VALUES
        (b.col_1, b.col_2, b.cnt_1, b.mapped_val);
```

Note that if you use `WHEN MATCHED AND` approach, tuples that match your `ON` predicate wouldn't qualify for the `WHEN NOT MATCHED`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that and it is very close to what I would like to achieve. The only exception is that `A2 B2 5 do_not_update_this` row in table `B` got added to `A` as a result. I updated my question with SQL fiddle link in case anyone would like to take a stab at it. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, then I guess your original query with `WHEN MATCHED AND a.cnt1 < b.cnt1` should work ?

Comment: I tried just for the sake of it, but I don't think `WHEN MATCHED AND a.cnt1 < b.cnt1` is allowed syntactically in Vertica (or maybe even the general SQL). Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure such syntax is allowed in SQL. At least my favorite database allows it :) https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html